# Does $L_1L_2 \notin RE$ imply $L_2L_1 \notin RE$?

Tags: computability

Given two languages $L_1, L_2$ such that $L_1L_2\notin RE$,
is it always true that $L_2L_1 \notin RE$?

I wasn't able to prove it or find a valid counterexample.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $L_1L_2$ is regular language then $L_2L_1$ is regular to?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/50308/if-l-1l-2-is-regular-language-then-l-2l-1-is-regular-to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be an arbitrary subset containing $0$. Define $L_1 = \{0^n 1 : n \in A\}$ and $L_2 = \{0^n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then $A$ reduces to $L_1L_2$, but $L_2L_1 = \{0^n1 : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.
but to my understanding your example doesn't give two languages that when concatenated are not recursively enumerable, no? because $$L_1L_2$$ and $$L_2L_1$$ are recursively enumerable, aren't they?

Comment: Note that $L_1$ is defined with respect to $A$, which is totally an arbitrary set. Hence you can choose $A$ such that $L_1$ would not be $RE$, and it will imply that $L_1L_2$ isn't as well (try to prove for yourself). But as you can see, $L_2L_1$ is $RE$.